# Symfony 3.4 - The service "Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap" has a dependency on a non-existent service "Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter"

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

Edit: My issue was resolved, see at the bottom of the post.

i've been trying to connect to a LDAP with Symfony 3.4 and i'm having quite troubles here.

i've setup my services.yml and security.yml following the documentation at https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/ldap.html and https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/ldap.html  and also https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/security.html

Here is my services.yaml

```
services:
  Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
      arguments:
      - host: myaddress
        port: 389
        #encryption: tls
        options:
          protocol_version: 3
          referrals: false
```

And here is my security.yaml

```
security:
    providers:
      my_ldap:
            ldap:
              service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
              base_dn: dc=corp,dc=com
              search_dn: "dc=corp,dc=com"
              search_password: password
              default_roles: ROLE_USER
              uid_key: uid
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: my_ldap
        anonymous: true
        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: 'uid={username},ou=People,dc=corp,dc=com'
        logout_on_user_change: true
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: login


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_MANAGER
    ROLE_MANAGER: ROLE_USER
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/manager, roles: ROLE_MANAGER }
    - { path: ^/myaccount, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I don't know why the dependency isn't found. I've checked the Ldap package with composer and everything was there. What am i missing ?

Thanks by advance for any clue or answer.

Edit: I managed to resolved my error. My service.yaml syntax was wrong
i used:

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
  arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
     arguments:
     #...
```

Where it should've been:

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
  arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
  arguments:
```

The tabulation for the second service was baddly made.

Comment: Have you consider to use Symfony autowire? https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/autowiring.html 
Don't belive the security section is important in this case.

Comment: Do you have the ldap-extension installed?

Comment: @NicolaPez : I'm not really familiar with autowire, I simply followed the Symfony LDAP documentation but this is interesting. I'll try with autowire and keep you informed.

@heiglandreas : Yes i do, i have installed it with composer. i've checked, re checked and reinstalled and it is there.

with `composer show`  i can see `Symfony/ldap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax of services.yaml was wrong: one indentation was misplaced